# How to make an incrementing loop for checking filename PHP

Tags: php, file, for-loop, increment

I have data's in server with file names like this(it's on a PDO) :

```
$row["control_number"]-201909A16.txt
$row["control_number"]-201910A15.txt
$row["control_number"]-201906A13.txt
$row["control_number"]-201910A06.txt
```

the `201910` is the date of the software revision made and the `A06` is the version of the software.

then I have a table looks like this :

```
| id | control_number   | data status | 
| 1  | 000000-0000      |  ON SERVER  |
```

The value will Output `ON SERVER` if the data with the same `or_number` is exist in the server, if not `File not found`

Now I'm thinking an incrementing loop to filter the filenames.

something like this :

```
///$IncrementFilename must be increment continuesly until it match a file name in the server

$path = 'http://127.0.0.0:0000/data/';
$path2 = $path.'/'.$row["control_number"].'/'.$row["control_number"].'.$IncrementFilename.'.txt' ; // declare exact path of data

if (fopen($path2, "r")) {
        $tbody .= '<td rowspan="" style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;cursor:pointer" class="ON-SERVER" id="">ON SERVER</td>';
    } else { //  IF FALSE 
        $tbody .= '<td rowspan="" style="vertical-align:middle;text-align:center;cursor:pointer" class="" id="">FILE NOT FOUND</td>';
    }
```

I don't know how to achieve it. So I can't show what I've tried so far..

Answer (score 0):

If we suppose that maximum value after `A` is two digits only, then I would suggest creating nested loops. The first one is for year, and the inner one for `A` values

```
function CheckOnServer($controlNum, $name) {
    $path = 'http://127.0.0.0:0000/data/' . $controlNum . '/' 
            . $controlNum . '-' . $name. '.txt';

    return fopen($path, "r");
}

$startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ym', '201901');
$endDate = new \DateTime();
while ($startDate->getTimestamp() < $endDate->getTimeStamp()) {
    $month = $startDate->format('Ym');
    for ($i = 0; $i <= 99; $i++) {
        $IncrementFilename = $month . 'A' . str_pad($i, 2, '0', STR_PAD_RIGHT);
        if (CheckOnServer($row["control_number"], $IncrementFilename)) {
            echo "ON SERVER";
        } else {
            echo "FILE NOT FOUND";
        };
    }
    $startDate->modify('+1 month');
}
```

Comment: I don't know what to put inside the function CheckOnServer() .. how can I return the result??

Comment: Do you have your files in a local folder?

Comment: No, it's on a shared server, and I use web chrome server to access it.. See the path that I put in my question..

Comment: I've updated my answer. Try the code, I've put there.

Comment: @ Dmitriy Gritsenko Output 'NOT FOUND' and also what is the use of $name and $date un CheckOnServer() ?? , then why do you put .date. in the path?

Comment: @Gelxxxx It's just a typo. Fixed that one.

Comment: @Gelxxxx Please consider upvoting for the answer, if it did help.